# Check for file existence if Laravel's Blade template

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a simple problem - how can I check if file exists in Laravel's Blade template?
 I tried

```
@if(file_exists('/covers/1.jpg')) ok @endif
```

But it doesn't work (`covers` directory is in `/public`). I also need to provide a variable (`$game->id`) to the function. Unformtunately,

```
@if(file_exists('/covers/'.$game->id.'.jpg')) ok @endif
```

doesn't work.

Comment: If your installation is in a sub directory then that absolute path won't work unless your sub directory is set to the document root. For example, if you access your site at `localhost/yoursite/public` then you'd need to use `/yoursite/public/covers/1.jpg` as `localhost` will be the document root.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is working for me, favicon.ico is inside public:

```
@if(file_exists('favicon.ico')) 
  File exists
@else
  Could not find file
@endif
```

So I think you just have to use `@if(file_exists('covers/1.jpg'))`

Answer (score 10):

In Laravel 4 you can use:

```
 @if (file_exists(public_path('covers/1.jpg')))
```

Use `public_path` to get the physical path to the file.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I need to know if blade template exists, not some public file. In this case best option was:

```
@if(\View::exists('some.view'))
  ...
@endif
```

Also could be useful:

`@includeIf('view.name', ['variable' => 'data'])` and `@includeWhen($condition, 'view.name', ['variable' => 'data'])`

It was tested in Laravel 8.0

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.8, I use it like this:

```
@if (file_exists (public_path ('filename.ico'))))
  << true, because the file exists >>
@other
  << false, because the file couldn't be found >>
@end if
```

If I use **asset()** instead of **public_path()**, it will not work correctly.

With Public_path() you will get the physical path of the file (from the public folder).

Answer (score 0):

```
@if (file_exists( 'public/images/user/'.$userData["avtar"]) ) 
     <a href="#"><img src="{{asset('images/user/'.$userData["avtar"])}}" alt="11"></a>

@else
     <a href="#"><img src="{{asset('bouts9/assets/images/profile/profile.png')}}" alt="Profile Picture"></a>

@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work with Laravel 8

```
file_exists("assets/images/image.extension")
```

file_exists directly looks inside the public path so you can directly pass path from within the public folder