# Laravel Blade: Try if imported php file exists

Tags: php, if-statement, laravel, include, laravel-blade

How would you do this **using blade's @import method**? I've tried:

```
@if (@include('/path/to/phpfile'))
    @include('/path/to/phpfile')
@else
    <h2>Oops! It doesn't look like this page exists!</h2>
@endif
```

also tried with `file_exists()`, no dice :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695300/check-for-file-existence-if-laravels-blade-template

Comment: already tried with `file_exists()` as stated. `File_exists()` doesn't get rendered through laravel's blade.

Comment: The file_exists() should work: unless you're providing the wrong path, I suspect it's your include that's wrong.... When you call @include('filename'), Blade automatically looks for any file with that name, inside the apps/views directory. Also, you're not supposed to write the file extension, as Blade automatically looks for files with .blade.php and .php extensions.

Comment: I meant that I want to be able to use blade's syntax of not including `.blade.php` for every file as well as being able to use `path.to.file` instead of `path/to/file` `file_exists()` requires that the file end with an extension

Comment: If you want to use files from other directories on the @include tag, add the directory to the paths array, on app/config/view.php.

Comment: nonono I just want to be able to look up a file in the `views` folder using blade's functionality

Comment: If you want to include a file in the `views` folder, then don't provide an absolute filepath

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may try this:

```
@if(View::exists('viewname'))
    @include('viewname')
@endif
```